# Overlapping of connectors in syncfusion

Tags: angular8, syncfusion

[image]

Expectation: Avoid overlapping of connectors or instead show connector below.

Answer (score 0):

We should set ports in the diagram node and establish a connection in the port to avoid overlapping of connectors. Please refer to a help documentation below in which we have explained how to create a node ports.

Help documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/diagram/ports/?no-cache=1

Please let us know whether it satisfies your requirement.

Regards,

Shyam G